# Finding Multiple regression coefficients

Tags: statistics

If I have a multiple regression like this $Y=a+b_1.X_1+b_2.X_2,$ how can I calculate the values of $b_1$ and $b_2$? I have searched on the web but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Generally look at the matrix notation for linear regression. Using linear algebra you can isolate the regression parameters.

Comment: Note we usually denote $a$ as $b_0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** rewrite
$$
Y = \left(
\begin{matrix}
  X_1& X_2& 1
   \end{matrix}\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
  \beta_1\\ \beta_2 \\ a
   \end{matrix}\right) = X\beta
$$and then apply the [multidimensional linear regression results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Introduction_to_linear_regression).

Comment: So I should solve them just lika a set of linear equations?

Comment: exactly. You have to solve $X^TX \beta = X^T Y$ for $\beta$.

Comment: Is the r-square value and RMS error for this case similar to how we calculate in single linear regression model i.e

Comment: i.e r-square by calculating the            1-{sumof(yactual-ypredicted)^2/sumof(yactual-ymean)^2}

Comment: yes, of course! this is just a vectorial formulation of the original problem. You can come back to the coefficients if you look at the coordinates of the solution!